# Can not comsume RabbitMQ in Docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I have installed RabbitMQ on Docker. I can send the mess to topic but I can not consume it.

```
 docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit  -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3.12-rc-management
```